# Questions about subversion and my VPS

Tags: svn, version-control, vps, mediatemple

I have just purchased a (dv) account from media temple and I want to begin using subversion, as currently I don't use a code repository at all.

Questions:

1. Should I setup svn on my (dv) or use something like beanstalk/assembla/etc for hosting my code repository? Basically i'm wondering if it's considered bad practice to have my code repository on the same (dv) that I serve all my websites/apps from?
2. Should I create a new repository for each website/app that I create or should I just create 1 repository and store all my projects in there?

Comment: If you're open to git, check out gitlabhq. I just set up their v2 of the private git site and it works really well. Just a thought.

Comment: You can get free mercurial/git hosting with bitbucket. Though it is not SVN, if this is your first exposure to version control, going with mercurial/git right of the bat would serve you well. You can skip the svn pain.

Comment: I'm open to git. I've used CVS at work, but they do not use it well there at all. I'm trying to steer clear of bad practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would not put my svn repo on the same server that you serve your websites from. Its a good and easy way to gain redundancy.
2. Separate repo for each project unless you are 100% sure you are the only developer that is going to touch those projects ever. Even then having them separate would be good. If you are on multiple computers you can just pull in updates for projects you are working on and not everything.